# Render multiple COG files using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geotiff-tiff, las, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I am able to render a single COG (Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF) file using OpenLayers examples

But, when when I go for rendering of multiple COG files, then it gives error.

How can I render multiple COG files using Open Layers?

Source Code: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog.html

This works (as single file working OK)

```
const source = new GeoTIFF({
    sources: [
        {
            url: 'https://indgeos-cog-test-1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cog0.tif'
        },
    ],
});
```

This Fails (as multiple files break)

```
const source = new GeoTIFF({
    sources: [
        {
            url: 'https://indgeos-cog-test-1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cog0.tif'
        },
        {
            url: 'https://indgeos-cog-test-1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cog1.tif'
        },
    ],
});
```

Error at Browser (on multiple rendering)

[image]

Comment: cross posted to StackOverflow: [Render multiple COG files using OpenLayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75269245/render-multiple-cog-files-using-openlayers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COGs within a GeoTIFF source must be able to use the same tile grid, but as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/multiple-cogs.html a layer can also have multiple GeoTIFF sources, so this should work

```
const source0 = new GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url: 'https://indgeos-cog-test-1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cog0.tif'
    },
  ],
});

const source1 = new GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url: 'https://indgeos-cog-test-1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cog1.tif'
    },
  ],
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  sources: [source0, source1],
});
```

Comment: const layer = new TileLayer({
    sources: [source0, source1],
  });

const map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: layer,
    view: source.getView(),
});

Comment: getting error as 'source is not defined' . source here is the variable at last line.
Can you further help me at rendering source ? 
Many Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `source.getView()`?  Use either `source0` or `source1` (or if they cover different areas use PromiseAll and combine the extents as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/multiple-cogs.html)